# How to Create White-Label Project using Expo React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, white-labelling

I am wondering how to create a white-label project in using react native without ejecting from expo. I understand how to use dynamic styles based on settings/configuration that I choose, but I do not get how to compile and publish the project with `app.json` matching those settings. Should I create multiple `app.json` files and use them for each setting/project I have?